# Need help with UK Direct Transit Visa (Indian Passport, valid US B1/B2 Visa Holder)

Tags: visas, uk, transit-visas

I'm an Indian passport holder, travelling to Buenos Aires via London Heathrow (Flight departs same day within 24 hours). I am also a valid B1/B2 US Visa Holder. Would I still require a DATV (Direct Airside Transit Visa) despite that?